External Widget Generated through API CSS Font
I have integrated 3 widgets from an external web site via API on the following page: https://pfxtrader.com/ar/latest-news/
The widgets are as follows:

Economic Calendar
News
Market

I am looking to apply a custom font (Cairo) from Google Font to all three widgets. The Cairo font is already loaded on the page.
While experimenting with CSS in Chrome Developer tools, the font is accepted. However, when I add it to the CSS section on the WordPress website, it does not work.
I have tried using the following selectors, but they did not yield the desired results:
#widget > div > figure > div{font-family:cairo !important;}

[class^='styled__WidgetBox-sc-'], [class*=' styled__WidgetBox-sc-'] 
{font-family:cairo !important;}

Please provide guidance on how to successfully apply the Cairo font to the widgets.
Update: The custom CSS is being added on the CSS field of the following page: https://pfxtrader.com/wp-admin/customize.php
I am open to any suggestion; even with jQuery
